# How to fetch data according to time

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to fetch data according to particular time. Suppose I am selecting dates 10 to 15(ie 2012-03-10 to 2012-03-15) and I want to fetch data between these dates only the 4th hour 
Then I should get data only 4th hr for these dates.

Suppose for 10th date on 4th hr data, for 11th date only 4th hr data and so on.

If I select any two dates in front end and select any hour in front end, I get only that hr.

Suppose I have a table

```
stime                      rnc 
2012-03-01 00:00:00        abc
2012-03-01 01:00:00        xyz
```

Comment: you should provide column name and table structure for more understanding

Answer (score 3):

Try using `between` and `to_char` functions.

```
SELECT rnc
  FROM table_name
 WHERE stime BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2012-03-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                 AND TO_DATE ('2012-03-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
   AND TO_CHAR (stime, 'hh') = 4;
```

Hope it helps.